# solution to the pde $u_{xx} -u_{yy}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am looking at solutions for the following PDE

$u_{xx}-u_{yy}=0$ One solution would be $u(x,y)=g(x-y)+h(x+y)$ with the two times differentiable functions $h,g$.

How do I prove that every solutions of the PDE are of that particular form ?

Edit: I try to answer this myself now. I got the following.

Using $s=x+y, t=x-y$ the PDE above is equivalent to $u_{st}=0$

Hence, $u_t=g'(t)$ $\implies u=g(t)+h(s)$ for some functions $g,h$.

I got one follow-up question. Why are those two functions two-times differentiable ?

Comment: Just an observation: $u(x,y) = a(x)b(y)$ yields solutions to the equation.

Comment: Because the PDE involves second derivatives, a solution $u$ must be twice differentiable to be able to satisfy it.

Answer (score 2):

You can view this as a wave equation with $c=1$. Look up d'Alembert's formula to find the proof you're interested in.